# How to make the isotope layout with flat bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, masonry

I'm using isotope js https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ and can't understand how to make my layout with flat bottom as here https://diefinnhutte.qodeinteractive.com/masonry-portfolio/.
I can't set fixed height for my blocks, but in example above I think isotope giving its own height.

How to make it?

I have simple code:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
  <div class="grid-item">...</div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.grid-item {width: 33%}
```

and js:

```
$('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
});
```

Inside grid-items I have img and they can be different height, so what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is because the example you give is technically not a *masonry* layout, but merely a grid. Masonries have different heights but equal spacings. For your example you don't need Isotope.

Comment: "I can't set fixed height for my blocks". Could you clarify why? That would solve your problem.

Comment: Because client will set image with different heights. You mean they are using css grid? It's 100% that they are using isotope, if you look at inline styles of blocks, you can easily see this.

Comment: Ah, I see. And the ratio's of the images have to honored or can the image "cover" an item in the isotope element? I mean that you don't have to use Isotope to create this layout, but it has its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Isotope is great for creating these layouts, but it has some quirks to work with. In your case you are working with images, and those images could dictate how the layout is calculated. I'd advise you to use the [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) library from the same author to first check if the images are loaded and then render the layout. Otherwise the items in the masonry layout would not have any height before the images are loaded.

If you want to have a layout that is flat on the top and on the bottom then you'll need some fixed height values. If the intact ratio of the images is more important than the height then it will simply not be possible.

You can use the `object-fit` property in CSS to give images a `background-size: cover` type of effect. It will make sure that any given image will be covering the entire space of an item in the masonry grid.

In these examples I've used multiple differently sized images that all work as they should despite their differences.

Check out the snippet with Isotope and imagesLoaded here below.

```js
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.grid-item',
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid-item.is-wide {
  width: 66.6666666%;
}

.grid-item::before {
  content: "";
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  display: block;
}

.grid-item::before,
.grid-item.is-wide.is-high::before {
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.grid-item.is-wide::before {
  padding-top: 50%;
}


.grid-item.is-high::before {
  padding-top: 200%;
}

.grid-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-wide">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/360/640" alt="360x640"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-high">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/420/420" alt="420x420"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item ">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/800" alt="640x800"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-wide">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/480/320" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/360/640" alt="360x640"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-wide">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/420/420" alt="420x420"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-high">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/800" alt="640x800"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item is-wide">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/480/320" alt="640x360"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's not what am I asking for, as you can see in example that I showed they are not using display: grid, because all images will be dynamic, and grid will not work for them perfect, I can't add class wide to elements, because I won't know is it will be wide or not. Sorry.

Comment: I've modified my answer to show the various column heights and removed the grid answer. If you are not able to set the width or height on any of those items then it is simply impossible to create that layout. You'll need to be able to control something or else all the items in the layout will be the same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the layout calculations in order to make this happen.

Now this can be complicated if there are items that span multiple columns. However if each item only spans one column, it is reasonably straightforward to do.

If you are using colspans the `equalizeProcessPositions()` method needs to do more advance calculations.

Logic:

- We need to know for each item which column it is positioned into. This info is not stored by default, so we override `_getTopColPosition` (when `horizontalOrder: false` (default)) and `_getHorizontalColPosition` (when `horizontalOrder: true`) in a way, that it does the same as before, but we assign a `col` property to each element, so we'll know later which column it is in.
- When each element is assigned into a column the `_processLayoutQueue()` method performs the positioning. Before that happens, we need to adjust the sizes and positions.
- First we find out the bottom position of each column. This is already available in a `colYs` property.
- Now we can find the tallest one and the rest. We will stretch the rest to match the tallest one. For this we calculate the height difference, divide it by the number of items, and modify the Y position and the height of each item in the shorter columns.
- We let the layout to be applied with the overridden positions and heights.
- We also need to hook into the layout reset function, otherwise the elements would be refitted with the adjusted heigh, resulting them to grow with each re-layout.

Here's the sample code:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var isotope = new Isotope( elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  layoutMode: 'masonry' // Note: this solution only works with 'masonry' layout!
});

const layoutMode = isotope._mode()

const _getTopColPosition = layoutMode._getTopColPosition
layoutMode._getTopColPosition = function( colSpan, item ) {
  const result = _getTopColPosition.apply( layoutMode, arguments );
  item.col = result.col;
  return result;
};

const _getHorizontalColPosition = layoutMode._getHorizontalColPosition
layoutMode._getHorizontalColPosition = function( colSpan, item ) {
  const result = _getHorizontalColPosition.apply( layoutMode, arguments );
  item.col = result.col;
  return result;
};

const isotopeProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(isotope);
isotopeProto._processLayoutQueue = function( queue ) {

  equalizeProcessPositions(queue);

  this.updateStagger();
  queue.forEach( function( obj, i ) {
    isotopeProto._positionItem( obj.item, obj.x, obj.y, obj.isInstant, i );
  }, this );
}

function equalizeProcessPositions(queue) {
  // Each item has a col attribute. Sort them into an object where the col number is the key and each value is an array of items
  const entriesByCol = queue.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    if (!acc[entry.item.col]) {
      acc[entry.item.col] = [];
    }
    acc[entry.item.col].push(entry);
    return acc;
  }, {});


  // colYs contains the height of each column
  const colYs = layoutMode.colYs
  // Get maxY for each col, i.e. the y position and the height of the last item
  const maxY = Math.max(...colYs);

  // Now adjust the items in each col
  for (const [col, colY] of Object.entries(colYs)) {
    if (colY !== maxY) {
      const diff = maxY - colY;
      const items = entriesByCol[col].length;
      const adjustment = diff / (items);

      // Loop each item in itemsByCol[i] and adjust the height and position
      for (const [i, entry] of Object.entries(entriesByCol[col])) {
        entry.item.size.innerHeight += adjustment;
        entry.item.size.outerHeight += adjustment;
        entry.item.size.height += adjustment;
        entry.item.element.style.height = entry.item.size.outerHeight + 'px';
        entry.y += i * adjustment;
      }
    }
  }
}


const _resetLayout = layoutMode._resetLayout
layoutMode._resetLayout = function() {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    item.element.style.height = '';
  })
  return _resetLayout.apply( layoutMode, arguments );
};
```